# Using DirectInput to receive signal after plugging in joystick

Tags: c++, directinput

I have a C++ program that enumerates all the input devices (using direct input) at the start of the program.  If the program is started, and then I plug in another controller, this controller won't be recognized until the program is restarted.  Anyone know of an event I can use that will cause my program to enumerate all of the devices after a new one is plugged in?

Answer (score 5):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20141211154922/http://www.spellofplay.com/blogs/hobbe/detecting-if-game-pad-plugged-or-removed.html) discusses how to detect game pad changes. First of all, you can handle the `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message and check `wParam` for `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` or `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE`. It seems that in order to receive these as `WPARAM`s, though, you need to call [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx) first.

The article's example of how to do this is as follows:

```
DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE notificationFilter;
ZeroMemory(&notificationFilter, sizeof(notificationFilter));
 
notificationFilter.dbcc_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE;
notificationFilter.dbcc_size = sizeof(notificationFilter);
 
HDEVNOTIFY hDevNotify;
hDevNotify = RegisterDeviceNotification(m_hWnd, &notificationFilter,
   DEVICE_NOTIFY_WINDOW_HANDLE |
   DEVICE_NOTIFY_ALL_INTERFACE_CLASSES);
 
if(hDevNotify == NULL) {
   // do some error handling
}
```

The only other thing to watch out for is that the minimum supported OS for this is XP, so you need to put in the appropriate `#define` for that before including the Windows headers.

Depending on what you want to do, you might not even have to call this function first. Instead, you can just check `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` to not differentiate between a device being plugged or unplugged. That could save some code if you don't care.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working. When any device is removed or added just dispose all 'IDirectInputDevice8' and re-create them. This avoids bugs and keeps things simple.

Hook WinProc method to watch for add/remove events

```
bool refreshInputDevices = false;
LRESULT SubWndProc(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // invalid code skip
    if (code < 0) return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);

    // check if device was added/removed
    PCWPSTRUCT pMsg = PCWPSTRUCT(lParam);
    if (pMsg->message == WM_DEVICECHANGE)
    {
        switch (pMsg->wParam)
        {
        case DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED:
            refreshInputDevices = true;
            break;

        case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            refreshInputDevices = true;
            break;

        case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
            refreshInputDevices = true;
            break;
        }
    }

        // continue as normal
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, code, wParam, lParam);
    }
```

Here is how you can hook on the input thread

```
// hook WinProc to watch for device changes
HMODULE module = GetModuleHandleW(NULL);
DWORD threadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
HHOOK hook = SetWindowsHookExW(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)&SubWndProc, module, threadID);
```